# Dúvida Classe C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Gostaria de entender o motivo de algumas classes em C++ possuírem a seguinte declaração:

```
class Bla;

class Ble
{
 ....
}
```

Minha dúvida é sobre a classe Bla, ela não tem sentido até onde eu consegui ver.

Comment: Realmente está sem sentido, precisaria de mais contexto e indicar melhor o que deseja saber. Talvez não saiba nada do que se trata, mas alguma indicação precisa ser dada. Ttalvez colocando um código real onde tem isso ajude.

Comment: Vou pegar um código de exemplo

Comment: Aqui está um exemplo: https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/dcdcee5afab6e8972f1b144ef7e7e884f85e83a3/Net/include/Poco/Net/HTTPStream.h#L35

Answer (score 8):

Isto se chama *forward declaration*. É necessário para permitir referências cíclicas entre classes. Assim é possível fazer a classe `Ble` ter um ponteiro para um objeto da classe `Bla` e depois fazer a classe `Bla` ter um ponteiro para um objeto da classe `Ble`:

```
class Bla;

class Ble
{
    Bla *bla;
};

class Bla
{
    Ble *ble;
};
```

A primeira linha serve para declarar que vai existir uma classe chamada `Bla`, mas sem ainda definir seu conteúdo. Com isso já é possível declarar ponteiros e referências para objetos dessa classe. Em um momento posterior é necessário definir o conteúdo da classe.

Além de resolver o problema de referências cíclicas, isto também evita a necessidade de se dar `#include` para obter a definição de classes quando só se deseja criar ponteiros ou referências. Nesse caso, por exemplo, em vez de dar `#include "bla.h"` é possível apenas fazer *forward declaration* da classe `Bla`. Fazer isso pode deixar o processo de compilação um pouco mais rápido.

Comment: Realmente, faz sentido! Muito bem explicado, agradeço pela resposta! pois essa dúvida me deixou muito curioso!

Comment: Novamente, obrigado por adicionar o termo correto, vou poder procurar mais detalhes!

Comment: Então vamos lá, declarei a classe Ble e ela tem como referencia Bla, se eu fizer o forward declaration eu não vou precisar definir o conteúdo da classe Bla antes da classe Ble?

Comment: Um pouco confuso de entender sem ver o código. Mas na prática o que isso permite é dizer que uma classe vai existir, mas sem indicar seu conteúdo. Você pode declarar um ponteiro de uma classe declarada assim, mas não pode criar objetos.

Comment: Vou te dar um exemplo https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/dcdcee5afab6e8972f1b144ef7e7e884f85e83a3/Net/include/Poco/Net/HTTPStream.h#L35