# C++ Ponteiros - Não consigo acessar função de um objeto instanciado em outra classe

Tags: c++, classes, ponteiro, passagem-por-referência

Criei um código simples para tentar explicar o meu problema. Primeiramente, o meu programa tem o seguinte:

Classes: "Game" e "Events".

Portanto tenho os seguintes arquivos:
**main**.cpp, **Game**.h, **Game**.cpp, **Events**.h,**Events**.cpp.

Em **main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"


int main() {
    Game* gameptr = new Game();
    gameptr->getEventsObject()->pollEvents(gameptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Em **Game.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include "Events.h"

class Game {
public:
    Game() {

    }
    Events * getEventsObject();
private:
    Events* eventsptr = new Events();
};
```

Em **Events.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

class Events {
public:
    Events() {

    }
    void pollEvents(Game * _game_ptr);
private:

};
```

Agora as implementações.

Em **Game.cpp**:

```
#include "Game.h"

Events * Game::getEventsObject() {
    return eventsptr;
}
```

Em **Events.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Events.h"


void Events::pollEvents(Game * _gameptr) {
    // Do something
}
```

Esses é o programa completo.
Diversos erros são mencionados pelo compilador, tais como:

> erro de sintaxe: identificador 'Game'

> -> Events::pollEvents': operando esquerdo possui tipo 'class', use'.'

> Erro  C3646   'getEventsObject': especificador de substituição
> desconhecido

Ainda não consegui compreender o erro.

Vamos lá, é assim que eu estou pensando ao codificar:
Eu criei a Classe Game para lidar com o funcionamento geral.
Dentro de Game criei um objeto de Events para lidar com entradas (mouse e teclado).

E em Main.cpp, onde está o loop principal, estou tentando acessar a função "pollEvents". Nesse exemplo não coloquei o loop porque é irrelevante para o problema que estou apresentando.

Comment: Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no [pt.so] são considerados ruído de comunicação. Boas perguntas são descritivas, detalhadas e diretas. Dê o máximo de informações possíveis sobre o que você quer fazer, erro encontrando e que já tentou, quem vai o ajudar não pode (nem quer) ficar conversando. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e Agradecimentos](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/137387) e [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/137387).

Comment: O que está ocorrendo é que criou referencias mutuamente dependentes entre as classes `Game` e `Events` então o compilador não consegue finalizar montagem das classes nessa condição. Para solucionar use [forward declaration]  que á apenas a palavra chave `class` seguida do nome da classe e um ponto e virgula que orienta ao compilador que um identificador de classe será utilizado porém essa ainda não está definida. Veja o exemplo: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/forward#main.cpp

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [C++: Arquivo header não reconhecendo classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210058/c-arquivo-header-n%c3%a3o-reconhecendo-classe)

Comment: Relacionado a [Dúvida Classe C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158035/137387)

Comment: @Augusto Vasques. Os links resolveram parcialmente a "lista de erros". Agora o compilador está acusando apenas o seguinte erro: C2027 "uso de tipo indefinido de 'Events'". O erro está apontado para a seguinte linha do código (em Games.h): `Events* eventsptr = new Events();`.

Comment: Chegou a ler isso https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/forward#main.cpp é o código da sua pergunta funcionando.

Answer (score -2):

> Ainda não consegui compreender o erro.

O erro está em você ter criado referências circulares a `Game` e `Events` e que o compilador não consegue resolver. Pode resolver usando `forward declarations` ou declarando `Events` interna a `Game`. Não parece haver sentido em uma classe sem a outra.

- Seu código parece bem inspirado nessa discussão: ["C++: event system implementation for a game engine"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946525/c-event-system-implementation-for-a-game-engine)

E tem uns exemplos aqui que pode usar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574016/game-objects-talking-to-each-other

#### Exemplo das tais `forward declarations`

#### `Events.h`

```
#pragma once
class Game;
class Events
{
   public:
    Events(){};
    void pollEvents(Game* _game_ptr);
}
```

#### `Game.h`

```
#pragma once
class Events;
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    Events* getEventsObject();
private:
    Events* eventsptr;
};
```